# How to change processing image dimension in GPUImage

Tags: gpuimage, gpuimagestillcamera

I'm tired to capture an image from `GPUImageStillCamera` and I got an image which has dimension 2592 X 1936 and 5.1 MB in size(and the image taken in iPad mini). This is too large(for my app). How to reduce the image dimension while capturing an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in response to [this GitHub issue you created](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/issues/1499), use `-forceProcessingAtSize:` on the first filter in your filter chain to lock it to a given size. If that size is larger than the default video size, you might want to do this right before you capture your photo, then set it back to 0 (using an unrestricted size) after the photo is captured.